# edit action similar to tutorial doesn't work

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-view, zend-framework3

I followed the ZF3 tutorial and I'm quite satisfied, but I'm something missing with the edit action in my controller. the add action works fine while the edit action doesn't. Probably I don't see it by myself, so I post it here, asking for help, even if it is really basic.

My model is nearly the same as in the tutorial, here a part of it:

```
public function exchangeArray(array $data)
{
    $this->ProjectID= !empty($data['ProjectID']) ? $data['ProjectID'] : null;
    $this->CI_Number= !empty($data['CI_Number']) ? $data['CI_Number'] : null;
    $this->Description= !empty($data['Description']) ? $data['Description'] : null;
    $this->Projectname= !empty($data['Projectname']) ? $data['Projectname'] : null;
    $this->Shortcut= !empty($data['Shortcut']) ? $data['Shortcut'] : null;
    $this->Component_Class= !empty($data['Component_Class']) ? $data['Component_Class'] : null;
}

public function getArrayCopy()
{
//      echo var_dump(get_object_vars($this)
//              );

        //return get_object_vars($this);
        return [
                'ProjectID'     => $this->ProjectID,
                'CI_Number' => $this->CI_Number,
                'Description'  => $this->Description,
                'Projectname'     => $this->Projectname,
                'Shortcut' => $this->Shortcut,
                'Component_Class'  => $this->Component_Class,
        ];
    }
```

and here also my controlleraction:

```
    public function editAction()
{
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    echo $id;
    if (0 === $id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('project', ['action' => 'add']);
    }
    else {
        try {
            $project = $this->projectTable->getProject($id);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('project', ['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $form = new ProjectForm();
        $form->bind($project);
        //$form->bind($project->current());
        $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'save changes');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $viewData = ['ProjectID' => $id, 'form' => $form];
        if (! $request->isPost()) {
            return $viewData;
        }
        $form->setInputFilter($project->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if (! $form->isValid()) {
            echo "nicht valide";
            return $viewData;
        }
        else{
        echo $project;
        $this->projectTable->saveProject($project);
        }
    }
    // Redirect to album list
//  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('project', ['action' => 'index']);
}
```

here for completion reasons my view edit.phtml:

```
    <?php
$title = 'projects';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h1><?= $this->escapeHtml($title) ?></h1>
<?php

// This provides a default CSS class and placeholder text for the artist element:



$ProjectID= $form->get('ProjectID');
$ProjectID->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
$ProjectID->setAttribute('placeholder', 'ProjectID');

$Projectname= $form->get('Projectname');
$Projectname->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
$Projectname->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Projectname');

$CI_Number= $form->get('CI_Number');
$CI_Number->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
$CI_Number->setAttribute('placeholder', 'CI_number');

$Shortcut= $form->get('Shortcut');
$Shortcut->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
$Shortcut->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Shortcut');

$Description= $form->get('Description');
$Description->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
$Description->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Description');

$Component_Class= $form->get('Component_Class');
$Component_Class->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
$Component_Class->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Component_Class');
// This provides CSS classes for the submit button:
$submit = $form->get('submit');
$submit->setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');

//$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('project', ['action' => 'edit',]));  //,'id'=> $id
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('project', [
    'action' => 'edit',
    'ProjectID'     => $id,
]));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>
<?php // Wrap the elements in divs marked as form groups, and render the
      // label, element, and errors separately within ?>


<div class="form-group">

    <?= $this->formElement($ProjectID) ?>
    <?= $this->formElementErrors()->render($ProjectID, ['class' => 'help-block']) ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->formLabel($CI_Number) ?>
    <?= $this->formElement($CI_Number) ?>
    <?= $this->formElementErrors()->render($CI_Number, ['class' => 'help-block']) ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->formLabel($Description) ?>
    <?= $this->formElement($Description) ?>
    <?= $this->formElementErrors()->render($Description, ['class' => 'help-block']) ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->formLabel($Projectname) ?>
    <?= $this->formElement($Projectname) ?>
    <?= $this->formElementErrors()->render($Projectname, ['class' => 'help-block']) ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->formLabel($Shortcut) ?>
    <?= $this->formElement($Shortcut) ?>
    <?= $this->formElementErrors()->render($Shortcut, ['class' => 'help-block']) ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->formLabel($Component_Class) ?>
    <?= $this->formElement($Component_Class) ?>
    <?= $this->formElementErrors()->render($Component_Class, ['class' => 'help-block']) ?>
</div>


<?php
echo $this->formSubmit($submit);
//echo $this->form->get('DCLID');
echo $this->formHidden($form->get('ProjectID'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

It will show the recordset properly, but won't save the changes to the database and afterwards redirects to my add action. I hope somebody sees what I'm missing, even it might be a stupid error.

EDIT1: Here is my routing link from index.phtml

```
  <a href="<?= $this->url('project', ['action' => 'edit', 'id' => $project->ProjectID]) ?>">Edit</a>
```

EDIT2: Screenshot to show the routing parameter

[image: routing parameter]

EDIT3: describing test issues

here again my controller edit action, to follow up:

```
public function editAction()
{
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    echo "variable id: ". $id;
    if (0 === $id) {
        //return $this->redirect()->toRoute('project', ['action' => 'index']);
        echo "id = 0";
    }
    else {
        try {
            $project = $this->projectTable->getProject($id);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('project', ['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $form = new ProjectForm();
        $form->bind($project);
        //$form->bind($project->current());
        $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'save changes');
        var_dump(get_object_vars($project));
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $viewData = ['ProjectID' => $id, 'form' => $form];
        if (!$request->isPost()) {
            return $viewData;
        }
        else {

            $form->setInputFilter($project->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if (!$form->isValid()) {
                echo "nicht valide";
                return $viewData;
            }
            else{
                echo "valide";
                echo $project;
                $this->projectTable->saveProject($project);
            }
        }
    }
    // Redirect to album list
//  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('project', ['action' => 'index']);
}
```

I get the output of the vardump, so the project to edit will be delivered correctly. If I send the form with the recordchanges the controller won't catch it, the controller action sees id=0 then, so the method saveProject will be never called. In my understanding it might has to do with the formvalid something, because after sending the data I come never further than `if (0 === $id)`.

EDIT 4: After some actual tests I think it must be a routing issue. If I give the route manually via browser, I won't get the target page at all. If I dump the value, it is always NULL. So I think it could be a bracket to much/to less issue in my `module.config.php` I show it here because I couldn't finde the problem, I countedt the braskets several times and I won't get it. So any help is appreciated, it must be a very simple topic:

```
    <?php
namespace Import;

use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

//use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
        /* 'controllers' => [
                'factories' => [
                        Controller\ImportController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
                ],
        ], */


        // hier die Einstellungen für die Routen
        'router' => [
                'routes' => [
                        'index' => [
                                'type'    => Segment::class,
                                'options' => [
                                        'route' => '/import[/:action[/:id]]',
                                        'constraints' => [
                                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                                        ],
                                        'defaults' => [
                                                'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                                                'action'     => 'index',
                                                        ],
                                            ],
                                    ],

                        'import' => [
                                'type'    => Segment::class,
                                'options' => [
                                        'route' => '/import[/:action[/:id]]',
                                        'constraints' => [
                                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                        ],
                                        'defaults' => [
                                                'controller' => Controller\ImportController::class,
                                                'action'     => 'index',
                                        ],
                                ],
                        ],

                        'importdcl' => [
                                'type'    => Segment::class,
                                'options' => [
                                        'route' => '/importdcl[/:action[/:id]]',
                                        'constraints' => [
                                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                        ],
                                        'defaults' => [
                                                'controller' => Controller\ImportdclController::class,
                                                'action'     => 'index',
                                        ],
                                ],
                        ],

                        'project' => [
                                'type'    => Segment::class,
                                'options' => [
                                        'route' => '/project[/:action[/:id]]',
                                        'constraints' => [
                                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                        ],
                                        'defaults' => [
                                                'controller' => Controller\ProjectController::class,
                                                'action'     => 'index',
                                        ],
                                ],
                        ],
                        'unit' => [
                                'type'    => Segment::class,
                                'options' => [
                                        'route' => '/unit[/:action[/:id]]',
                                        'constraints' => [
                                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                        ],
                                        'defaults' => [
                                                'controller' => Controller\UnitController::class,
                                                'action'     => 'index',
                                        ],
                                ],
                        ],

                        'index' => [
                                'type'    => Segment::class,
                                'options' => [
                                        'route' => '/index[/:action[/:id]]',
                                        'constraints' => [
                                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                        ],
                                        'defaults' => [
                                                'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                                                'action'     => 'index',
                                        ],
                                ],
                        ],
                        'user' => [
                                'type'    => Segment::class,
                                'options' => [
                                        'route' => '/user[/:action[/:id]]',
                                        'constraints' => [
                                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                        ],
                                        'defaults' => [
                                                'controller' => Controller\UserController::class,
                                                'action'     => 'index',
                                        ],
                                ],
                        ],
                        'followup' => [
                                'type'    => Segment::class,
                                'options' => [
                                        'route' => '/followup[/:action[/:id]]',
                                        'constraints' => [
                                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                        ],
                                        'defaults' => [
                                                'controller' => Controller\FollowupController::class,
                                                'action'     => 'index',
                                        ],
                                ],
                        ],
                ],
        ],



        'view_manager' => [
                'template_path_stack' => [
                        'import' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
                ],
        ],



            /* ... */

        'navigation' => [
                        'default' => [
                                [
                                        'label' => 'Dashboard',
                                        'route' => 'home',

                                ],
                                [
                                        'label' => 'Project',
                                        'route' => 'project',
                                        'pages' => [
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Add',
                                                        'route'  => 'project',
                                                        'action' => 'add',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Edit',
                                                        'route'  => 'project',
                                                        'action' => 'edit',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Delete',
                                                        'route'  => 'project',
                                                        'action' => 'delete',
                                                ],
                                        ],
                                ],
                                [
                                        'label' => 'Unit',
                                        'route' => 'unit',
                                        'pages' => [
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Add',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'add',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Edit',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'edit',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Delete',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'delete',
                                                ],
                                        ],
                                ],
                                [
                                        'label' => 'Importlog',
                                        'route' => 'importdcl',
                                        'action' => 'index',
                                        'pages' => [
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Add',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'add',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Edit',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'edit',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Delete',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'delete',
                                                ],
                                        ],
                                ],

                                [
                                        'label' => 'Follow up',
                                        'route' => 'followup',
                                        'action' => 'index',
                                        'pages' => [
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Add',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'add',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Edit',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'edit',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Delete',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'delete',
                                                ],
                                        ],
                                ],

                                [
                                        'label' => 'User',
                                        'route' => 'user',
                                        'pages' => [
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Add',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'add',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Edit',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'edit',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Delete',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'delete',
                                                ],
                                        ],
                                ],

                                [
                                        'label' => 'Logout',
                                        'route' => 'user',
                                        'action' => 'logout',
                                        'pages' => [
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Add',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'add',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Edit',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'edit',
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        'label'  => 'Delete',
                                                        'route'  => 'unit',
                                                        'action' => 'delete',
                                                ],
                                        ],
                                ],

                        ],
                ],



        /* ... */

];
```

I'm testing in the `usercontroller` at the moment, but I have had the same problem in others routes, so I think the error might be in this file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, seem the problem is on `$id`. It mean the value is `0`, that's why it is redirected to `project/add`.

```
$id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
echo $id;
if (0 === $id) {
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('project', ['action' => 'add']);
}
```

In your view script, the form action is set to `project/edit/ProjectID/$id`

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('project', [
    'action' => 'edit',
    'ProjectID'     => $id,
]));
```

That's why your controller cannot retrieve `$this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0)`, because the form send `ProjectID` param instead of `id`.

So, the solution please adjust your form (using `id`) or your controller (using `ProjectID`).

Comment: No, if I change like you suggested I won't get the data exploded in the form, I will edit my post and add my routing link.

Comment: Just replace `ProcjectID` in `$form->setAttribue('action', ...` to `id`. If you still use `ProjectID` the form will submit to `/project/edit/ProjectID` instead of `/project/edit/id/`.

Comment: I think it might be another problem, of course I tried, i will explain it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I at last solved it. My suggestion was right, it was a problem with the module.config.php, I have set an endbracket at the wrong place.

After writing it in parts new, tsting and complete the file, it now works.

Comment: This case should be avoid using a right IDE. What is your IDE?

Comment: I'm using eclipse, I don't know any IDE that shows you the right place, it shows only if brackets missing or double. In this case the blocks were quite wrong, but the amount of closing brackets was the same like opening. Quite stupid and disgusting error ;-)

Comment: Yes, but we can jump to the closing bracket to check it close the code block like expected or not